# Segue to Another Storyboard Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode-storyboard

I am attempting to segue to another storyboard programmatically, but every time I've tried the view loads with a black screen with no content.

Here's the code I've been working with:

```
let storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let startingView = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("HomeScreenView")
self.showViewController(startingView, sender: self)
```

I've created the reference on the Origin's Storyboard of the Destination Storyboard and have also tried to call:

```
performSegueWithIdentifier("changeover", sender: self)
```

Any thoughts and suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: segue to storyboard is wrong. You can only segue between controllers in storyboard.

Comment: I am attempting to segue to a storyboard, I have used a storyboard reference.

Comment: I think you need to use `presentViewController` or `present(viewControllerToPresent: )` if you're using swift 3 to `present` a `viewController` .

Answer (score 8):

I've haven't had issues using Storyboard References with segues. Here are the steps I've followed to get it working:

1) In the storyboard with the source view controller, drag a storyboard reference onto the canvas.

2) Set the reference to point to the correct storyboard name and view controller in the attribute inspector

3) Ctrl+drag from the source's view controller icon (in the top bar of the scene) to the storyboard reference in order to create a segue.

4) Set the segue to "Show" and give it the identifier "Test" in the attribute inspector

5) In your source view controller's code, at the appropriate location where you want it triggered, add the line:

```
performSegueWithIdentifier("Test", sender: self)
```

That should be everything needed for the segue to be called programmatically!

Comment: 2) Set the reference to point to the correct storyboard name and view controller in the attribute inspector

Comment: let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PageViewController") as UIViewController
            presentViewController(controller, animated: false, completion: nil)

Comment: I got an error that says "ViewController has no segue with identifier 'Test'. The other storyboard is named "Extras' and the view controller scene I want to show from it is called 'Test'.

Answer (score 3):

***"MyStoryBoard" this is the storyboard name where you want to go
"StoryboardId" this is the controller id which i want to show after segue.***

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Service", bundle: nil)
    let myVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ProfileTimelineVC") as! ProfileTimelineVC
    self.present(myVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 1):

In AppDelegate append var window: UIWindow?

```
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Registration", bundle: nil)
    let registrationvc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: 
        "RegistrationViewController") as! RegistrationViewController
    self.window?.rootViewController?.present(registrationvc, animated: true, 
    completion: nil)
```